# Restarting process gives 'start: Rejected send message' error

Tags: linux, azure

In a VM procured through Azure Cloud Services, the `status` of a process called `walinuxagent` upon doing `service walinuxagent status` is:

`walinuxagent stop/waiting`

Next I do `service walinuxagent start`. I end up getting:

`start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.1551" (uid=1000 pid=59402 comm="start walinuxagent ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")`

Can someone help out with diagnosing and fixing this issue? Essentially, I added swapfile settings to walinuxagent, and I'm now trying to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, I added swapfile settings to walinuxagent, and I'm now
>   trying to restart it.

Do you mean you just modify waagent.conf to add swap file?
If yes, we can remove walinuxagent and re-install it, then modify waagent.conf to add swap file.

To delete configuration and data files of walinuxagent and it's dependencies from Ubuntu trusty:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove walinuxagent
```

Then use apt-get to install walinuxagent:

```
apt-get install walinuxagent
```

then check the walinuxagent status.

**Update:**

As a workaround, we can copy a new `waagent.conf` file to this VM `/etc/waagent.conf` Then use `sudo service walinuxagent start` to start waagent.

Comment: I update my answer, please check. the first error means you should use `sudo` to start service. stop/pre-start  seems the waagent.conf was wrong,  so we can delete the conf file, and copy a new conf file to this VM, then use `sudo service walinuxagent start` to start the service.

Comment: Does it work now?